# Detecting an open door in a RGB-Image using a kinect and OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect, object-detection

I need to be able to identify an opened door in an image taken from a kinect camra mounted on a robot. 
The problem is that most of the time the image won't capture the entire door but only the lower half.

So I can't just train a HOG detector for doors because it would need to be trained on the entire door frame.

I am also able to get the whole range of kinect depth images. Would it be possible to look for something like a "hole in the wall" an assume that is a door?

Comment: that would exactly be what I would try: Detect walls that have a "hole" with a width of x to y cm (typically doors are more or less standardized)

Comment: oh wait... do you only have RGB image or can you use Depth sensor too??

Comment: Train a HOG detector on whatever the robot will see... Just because you define a 'door' to be the full frame, doesn't mean the detector wont work on the lower half. Or just use the depth info directly, but we'd need to know the full context of the environment to know if there would be false positives, and how to potentially deal with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found this algorithm on the net.

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html#gsc.tab=0

Now that I am able to reliably identify verticl edges in the picture, i can check them against my depth senosr data, to see if they are edges of an open door.

E.g.: if the depth to the right of the edge is far greater than on the left, its probably the left edge of the door.

With this i can identify the area "door" pretty acuratly.

I hope this can help someone else as well.